# Nuxt на Ubuntu не может получить ресурс по ссылке

Tags: ubuntu, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js

На локальном (Windows 10) простое, базовое приложение Nuxt.js работает. Переходит по ссылкам и подключает изображения.
То же самое приложение склонированное на Ubuntu 18 (nginx на сервере) не подключает изображения, не подключает скрипты, а при переходе на другую страницу не находит эту страницу (/inspire по умолчанию).

Никаких ошибок не показывает, билдится, запускается. Одна проблема - по тем путям которые указаны в DOM не может получить ни скрипт, ни изображение.

Сам каталог находится var/www/html/nodex

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в настройке nginx.
А именно в строчке - `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`
Так, невозможно было получить доступ к файлам.